# How can I implement jQuery's .wrapInner() function in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm making a bookmark in plain javascript, and I'd like to wrap all of the site's original body content in a div, so that I can separate that content from what I am adding...

In my scenario, I'm trying to add a fixed, vertical, full-width nav, but I'd like to add padding to the rest of the content.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it so important to not use jQuery? It's a powerful tool that will simply do exactly what you require?

Comment: @PatrickEaton: jQuery is very often just too much code to load for simple problems, especially if you're not supporting IE6 and 7.

Answer (score 7):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

while(document.body.firstChild)
    div.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

---

Or

```
var div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

while(document.body.firstChild !== div)
    div.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
```

---

And of course you can make them into a function, by passing the parent and optionally the desired container as a node name or a node.

```
function wrapInner(parent, wrapper) {
    if (typeof wrapper === "string")
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrapper);

    var div = parent.appendChild(wrapper);

    while(parent.firstChild !== wrapper)
        wrapper.appendChild(parent.firstChild);
}
```

then

```
wrapInner(document.body, "div");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be:

```
var dv = document.createElement('div');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var elements = body.childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
     dv.appendChild(elements[i]);
}
body.appendChild(dv);
```

Comment: Once you've appended `elements[i]` to the `dv`, it has been removed from `body` since a node can't be in two places at the same time. That means you'll get a DOM Exception when you try to do `body.removeChild(elements[i]);`. You should just remove that line.

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you! It's night here in Riga, Latvia already :D

Comment: You're welcome. But I think there's one more problem. The `body.childNodes` is a live list, so as you move the nodes, they're removed from the list. This means you'll be skipping over nodes as `i` increments.